# How to load weights from a specific checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I have a checkpoints saved from different experiments and I would like to load weights from a particular checkpoints that gave better results. How do I do that? `tensorflow` docs only show how to load the latest weights. Is there a way to load weights from a specific checkpoint? Below is the list of checkpoints I have in my `./checkpoints` directory:

```
os.listdir('./checkpoints/')

## prints:
['checkpoint',
 'cp.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001',
 'cp3.ckpt.index',
 'cp.ckpt.index',
 'cp3.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001']
```

I would like to load the weights with `cp3` checkpoints?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].